# Sum all field with the other field < itself in sqlite

Tags: sqlite, android-sqlite, system.data.sqlite

Sorry because I dont think good title for my problem.
I have table a(f1 integer, date Long), date increase, and the data

```
f1       date
1        1
2        2
3        3
...
```

I need to sum f1 by date, with record 1{1,1} the sum f1 is 1,with record 2 the sum f1 is 1+2, record 3 the sum f1 is 1+2+3...
How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

This requires a [correlated subquery](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Correlated_subquery):

```
SELECT date,
       (SELECT SUM(f1)
        FROM a AS a2
        WHERE a2.date <= a.date
       ) AS f1_sum
FROM a
ORDER BY date;
```

But it's inefficient. Consider just scanning the table, sorted by the date, and summing `f1` as you're reading it.